# Method must override super class method

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working through some android tutorials right now in preparation for a two week camp at American university. I'm seventeen, so excuse me if this is a stupid question. I did some research and tried several things, but I can't get it to work.

I'm working off of the google tab / fragment example found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

My problem is when overriding createTabContent, and onTabChanged I keep getting the error must override a superclass method. Here's my code:

package matthews.zack.test;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class _testActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
ListView list;
Button save;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton selectedType;
TabHost tabHost;
// People p = new People();
public List<People> people = new ArrayList<People>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    onInitialize();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }
}

private void onInitialize() {

    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

     * TabManager tManager = new TabManager(this, tabHost,
     * R.id.realtabcontent); tManager.addTab(
     * tabHost.newTabSpec("details").setIndicator("Details",
     * getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.goldstar)), null, null);
     * tManager.addTab( tabHost.newTabSpec("list").setIndicator("List",
     * getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bluestar)), null, null);
     *

     * TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
     * spec.setContent(R.id.listView1); spec.setIndicator("List",
     * getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.goldstar));
     * 
     * TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
     * spec2.setContent(R.id.details); spec2.setIndicator("Details",
     * getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bluestar));
     * 
     * tabHost.addTab(spec); tabHost.addTab(spec2);
     */

    PeopleAdapter adapter = new PeopleAdapter();
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.type);
    // radioGroup.check(R.id.coWorker);
    radioGroup
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (selectedType != (RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroup
                            .getCheckedRadioButtonId())) {
                        selectedType = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroup
                                .getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                    }
                }
            });

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            People p = new People();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            p.setFirstName(firstName.getText().toString());// firstName.getText().toString());
            p.setLastName(lastName.getText().toString());// lastName.getText().toString());
            p.setType(selectedType.getText().toString());

            people.add(p);
        }
    });
}

static class PeopleHolder {
    private TextView name;
    private TextView title;
    private ImageView icon;

    PeopleHolder(View row) {
        name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }

    void populateForm(People p) {
        name.setText(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName());
        title.setText(p.getType().toString());
        if (p.getType().equals("Family")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

        }

        else if (p.getType().equals("Friend")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.xbox);
        }

        else {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.yinyang);
        }
    }

}

class PeopleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<People> {

    PeopleAdapter() {
        super(_testActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                people);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        PeopleHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new PeopleHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            holder = (PeopleHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.populateForm(people.get(position));

        return (row);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("tab", tabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
}

public static class TabManager implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
    private final FragmentActivity activity;
    private final TabHost host;
    private final int containerID;
    private final HashMap<String, TabInfo> tabs = new HashMap<String, TabInfo>();
    TabInfo lastTab;

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            this.tag = _tag;
            this.clss = clss;
            this.args = args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context context;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(context);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);

            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabManager(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost host,
            int containerID) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.host = host;
        this.containerID = containerID;
        this.host.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(activity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

        info.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(tag);

        if (info.fragment != null && !info.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(info.fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        tabs.put(tag, info);
        host.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        TabInfo newTab = tabs.get(tabId);
        if (lastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            if (lastTab != null) {
                if (lastTab.fragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(lastTab.fragment);
                }

            }

            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                    newTab.fragment =       Fragment.instantiate(activity,
                            newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                    ft.add(containerID, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);

                }

                else {

                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }

            }

            lastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .executePendingTransactions();

        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

}
```

Is this an eclipse problem, or did I make a careless mistake? I checked and double checked that I was using the proper classes and that they contained the methods I'm trying to override. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Full code posted. I'm able to compile and run, but the app force closes as soon as it's launched. Please help!

Comment: How is your class that contains onTabChanged declared?

Comment: People in this community volunteer their time to help you, you really should accept the correct answers to your old questions even if the best answer isn't perfect.

Comment: Can you show us the entire class code please?

Comment: Yeah let me post the entire class code.

Comment: Your overriding methods need to be in the class that extends your super class. It looks like your overriding method is outside that class.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean? From what it looks like, they are.

Comment: If you are getting a force close, can you post the crash log you get from logcat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably using a different Java version than the author of your example code... You have two choices:

1. You should be able to remove the `@Override` lines causing the errors and run your app without any trouble.
2. You can change your JDK Compiler's compliance level from 1.5 to 1.6 in Eclipse:

   **Properties** -> **JDK Compiler** -> Select "1.6" from the **Compiler compliance level** dropdown
   (Android only supports 1.5 and 1.6, it does not yet support 1.7)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all the code of your class, it's hard to say what you problem is exactly.

Like Sam said, depending on the examples you are using, you may not need to use @Override. If you class doesn't "extend" anything like:

```
public class MyClass extends MySuperClass{...
```

Then you don't need the over ride.  Overriding is done when you have a super class that you are inheriting methods from, and you want to change the way they function. Think of it as customizing methods that are stored in the class you are extending. If you don't have a super class, you don't need to override the methods, which may be causing your problem.

The other issue might be that you aren't overriding the correct methods within the super class.

But without seeing all the code, it is hard to give you something more specific.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I posted my full code, can you help me a little better? I'm getting a force close now.

Comment: One things I've found with overriding in Eclipse, is that if you get rid of the override annotation, the do a  Project > clean; it will give you an error saying "must override method..." from there you can hover over the error lines and you will get an option to have the IDE import the methods with the override annotation. That might work.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Java don't like the use of @Override for Interface method overrides. Back then only Super Class methods were meant to be used with that annotation. This is changed after 1.5, so 1.6 and 1.7 don't throw warnings for @Override for overriding an Interface method.

You can either suppress this warning, remove the annotation (this doesn't hurt you at all, but if you type the method name or argument type wrong, Eclipse won't tell you), or you can change  to 1.6 or higher.

Comment: Suppressing warnings is poor coding. It's like driving down the road with your check engine light on. Warnings are there for a reason. It would make more sense to upgrade your version of Java, than to just suppress the warnings.

Comment: The warning I am talking about is not there for a reason. It's a deprecated warning. Please do some research before voting down my response. You can see here that the ability to use the @Override annotation for interfaces was only added in 1.6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why
It's not a real warning. Although, my post may not solve the OP's question, but that doesn't make it any less valid.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem some time ago and solved it by changing the project's compilance level to 1.6.

To do this:

- Right Click on the project folder (can be found in Eclipse's Project Explorer, left side)
- Properties
- Java Compiler
- Uncheck "Enable project specific settings
- Configure Workspace Settings...
- And then change the compilance level from 1.5 to 1.6

Comment: I don't think that this will solve the problem. When you do something like changing the compliance level, you might be creating more problems than you are solving. Before anything is done, you should see all the code and make sure that there is something else. We are talking about an issue with over-riding a superclass method. He may not even have a super class, so why would he want to change the compliance level?

Comment: When I had this problem I read a topic somewhere and it said to change the compilance level to 1.6 because 1.5 had a problem with overrides. And it works perfectly after that.

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's right. This could be compared to suppressing warnings. Every time you have an issue with an over ride, you don't just want to start changing your compliance level. There is usually a good reason why you are getting the warnings, and should try and figure out what they are before you go and start adjusting your settings. Ultimately it amounts to poor coding and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: It is not a solution to the error. It is just a measure or a solution out of luck. It sounds like designing an application for tablets but then changing its compatibility to phones when it does not work for tablets, instead of finding the real source of the issue.